# ADB shell command to Get Device Rom Version and Save to Text File

Tags: shell, adb

I know that if I use the following command, I will get the ROM version of the device:

adb shell getprop "ro.product.version"

I want my program to be able to read this value from a text file, but how can I get the ROM version using the adb shell command above and then save that result into a text file saved anywhere on the c drive of the computer.  I can not seem to find how to save the results of adb shell command anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question and I thought I would post it in case anyone has the same question.  This adb shell command will get the ROM version and save it to the file and save it to the selected directory location:

```
adb shell getprop "ro.product.version" > C:/RomVersion/ROM.txt
```